# React: 'db' is not exported from '../firebase'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, import, export

my importing statement is:

`import { auth, provider, storage, db } from "../firebase";`

but in the terminal i have the error :

```
Failed to compile.
./src/actions/index.js
Attempted import error: 'db' is not exported from '../firebase'.
```

Am I importing/exporting it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting a reference to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference), the syntax for the new v9 (and later) SDKs is:

```
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const database = getDatabase();
```

I recommend keeping the documentation handy, as the new syntax is quite different from the one that had been in use since 2016 - and most tutorials outside of firebase.google.com are likely not updated yet.